# RDCMAN Remote Desktop Connection Manager doesn't allow all clicks or clicking

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I'm using RDCMAN 2.2 from WIN7 x64 to WIN7 x64.

I can login fine to remote boxes and see the remote desktop, and see the mouse move,
but!, I cannot click on everything I see IExplorer highlight as I move the mouse over it,
but I cannot click it.
Even stranger, I can successfully click the icon next to IExplorer, Media Player.

I also cannot click the Windows Start button.

I do not have any of these problems when I use the 'remote desktop' program itself.

I would guess this is a security issue.

Comment: I experience the same issue. It sounds like a refresh problem

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same behaviour : disabling Themes in the Tools/Options results seems to have fixed the issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution is very simple.Go to your display setting

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

and change the display settings to Medium and restart your computer.

It will fix the issue